# Manage Hyperlink base on the condition in Repeater ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

How to manage Hyperlinks base on AttachmentID, In Inside link button there is two hyperlink to manage, If AttachmentID is "NA" Then Hyperlink ID one should visible else Hyperlink ID two should visible. I tried lots into google like this code not able to find. I tried using ItemCommand and ItemDataBound but did not understand this concept. The main concept to do this manage target="_blank".

Below is my Repeater Code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_News1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_News1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" class="pull-left img-responsive" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/images/news_images/{0}") %>' />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_check" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Attachmentid") %>'>

            <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Attachment")%>' id="one"
                 target="_blank">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Heading")%></a> 

               <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Attachment")%>' id="two">

                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Heading")%></a> 

            </asp:LinkButton>
            </h4>
            <p>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SmallDescription")%></p>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your repeater:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Attachment") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("AttachmentID").ToString() != "NA" %>' Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.Heading") %>' Target="_blank" />
```

You can set the Visibility with an if statement in the HyperLink itself: `Visible='<%# Eval("AttachmentID").ToString() != "NA" %>'`

**UPDATE**

You can also check the `AttachmentID` for `IsNullOrEmpty` and show the correct hyperlink.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Attachment") %>' Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("AttachmentID").ToString()) %>' Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.Heading") %>' Target="_blank" />

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Attachment") %>' Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("AttachmentID").ToString()) %>' Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.Heading") %>' Target="_self" />
```

Comment: I am not Visible attachment ID, I want to visible hyperlink base on attachment Id. If attachment ID is null then target Blank open is new page else some values then open in same page url. @VDWWD

Comment: I am getting this error: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DataItem'. @VDWWD

Comment: Try `Text='<%# Eval("Heading") %>'`. I just copied the names from your snippet.

Comment: Thank you so and so much, may I know after added work fine. @VDWWD