# c# How to pass an Int parameter using Onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

I need to pass an int parameter to an Onclick event in my code behind, in my example, I've tried this:

```
<%  for (int index = 0; index < UploadDocs.Count;index++ )
        {               
       %>
  <asp:ImageButton runat="server"
                    visible="false" 
                    CommandArgument='<%=Eval("index")%>'
                    ID="Btn_RemoveOtherPJ"
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/W4_remove.gif"
                    OnClick="RemoveAttachedDoc_Button_Click" /><%}%>
```

and in my code behind :

```
    protected void RemoveAttachedDoc_Button_Click(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)source;
        int index = Int32.Parse(btn.CommandArgument);
        UploadDocs.RemoveAt(index);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ImhotepHelper.ManagedError(exception, Context);
    }
}
```

problem is that the CommandArgument is not read as a string neither an int:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcLV1.png)

Comment: You should use a Repeater Control.

Comment: Yes, it's better to use it but, can't I just pass a simple parameter to the onclick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850056/5836671

Comment: so I must use a repeater?

Comment: That is the easiest solution and you can bind an Eval like in my answer in the link I posted.